# Recovering partitioned drive

Tags: dual-boot

I have recently formatted my computer that previously had dual boot: windows 7 and Ubuntu 10, and changed my OS to windows 8. Even though the ubuntu drive was left untouched, the computer now neither boots ubuntu nor recognises the partitioned drive even with ubuntu OS (older version).

Any help please. or need more specification, please let me know.

Comment: You probably have to update grub.

Answer (score 1):

When you install windows 8 on the partition of windows 7 it replaces the ubuntu grub on the 
 Master Boot Record (MBR) which is a special type of boot sector at the very beginning of the hardisk.
The grub which contains the location of ubuntu is wiped and replaced with windows 8 boot partiton
Solution i could take if i were you :
  get a gparted live image either on a CD or USB and boot it, it will tell you whether the ubuntu partition exists .
If it does you can use a ubuntu live image to restore the grub

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **[testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)** to search for the lost partitions. It is able even to recover partition table in most of the cases.

If that doesn't work well and you don't succeed to recover the partition, you can still try to use **[photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)** which can recover the files on the lost partition.

If you choose to use testdisk could you please *give us the results* of the execution.